# UnicodeEncodeError when sending request to API

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using this code to send requests:

```
r = requests.post(
    "http://127.0.0.1:5000/query",
    data=json.dumps({"msg":"वडिलांचा नाव कार्डवर चुकीचा आहे"},ensure_ascii = False), 
    headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"}
)
```

but I get an error =>

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 9-16: Body ('वडिलांचा') is not valid Latin-1. Use body.encode('utf-8') if you want to send it encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Does encoding the JSON work?  `r=requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/query",data=json.dumps({"msg":"वडिलांचा नाव कार्डवर चुकीचा आहे"},ensure_ascii = False).encode('utf-8'), headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"})`

Comment: Removing the `ensure_ascii=False` seems like absolutely the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `{"msg":"वडिलांचा नाव कार्डवर चुकीचा आहे"}` may contains invalid unicode. In order to send the response, either remove `ensure_ascii=False` from the `json.dumps` or `encode('utf-8')` it. Then it will not throw any error.

```
r = requests.post(
    "http://127.0.0.1:5000/query",
    data=json.dumps({"msg":"वडिलांचा नाव कार्डवर चुकीचा आहे"}, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8), 
    headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"}
)
```

Or, we can just simply use `json.dumps` with `ensure_ascii=False`

```
r = requests.post(
    "http://127.0.0.1:5000/query",
    data=json.dumps({"msg":"वडिलांचा नाव कार्डवर चुकीचा आहे"}), 
    headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"}
)
```